# convert bitmap to image with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, bitmap, type-conversion

I use robotjs to capture screen.it returns a bitmap object,but I don't know how to convert the bitmap object to a image.
Is there anyone know the answer? showing me a example is better.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is to convert your bitmap to base64. Then you can show it in your html and allow users to download it.

```
bitmap.image.toString('base64')
```

Where 'image' is your bitmap.

Seems a duplicate of : [How to convert a bitmap with javascript to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499872/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-with-javascript-to-an-image)

Comment: before showing it in html Should I add a header (like that:data:image/png;base64,)in front of the base64 string ?if do  I want to know whtat data type should I set?

Comment: Is your bitmap stored in your javascript ?

Comment: Yes In my server(express),I got a bitmap like that:
var bitmap = robot.screen.capture(0, 0, 500, 500);
<!--the bitmap`s format is like that:{"width":500,"height":500,"byteWidth":2000,"bitsPerPixel":32,"bytesPerPixel":4,"image":{"type":"Buffer","data":[252,250,250,255,252,250,250,255,252,250,250,255,252,250,250,255,252,250,250,255,252,250,250.......]}-->
    var imageString=bitmap.image.toString('base64');
    imageString="data:image/bmp;base64,"+imageString
In my client,I got the encoded string data,I used like that:document.getElementById("image").src = data;
but it does not works.